# ASP.NET Core - How to convert SQL Server statement to Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have this SQL Server query which works and gives the desired result in SQL Server:

SQL Server query:

```
SELECT
  s.RegNumber,
  s.AdmissionDate,
  c.CourseName
FROM student AS s
JOIN student_course AS sc
  ON s.id = sc.StudentId
JOIN course AS c
  ON c.id = sc.CourseId
WHERE c.Id = '67A21699-DFE6-4CB6-96B6-E009FD389596';
```

StudentCourses:

```
public class StudentCourses
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid StudentId { get; set; }
    public Guid CourseId { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I tried to turn it to ASP.NET Core-6 Entity Framework as shown below:

```
var sc = Context.StudentCourses
                .Where(x => x.CourseId == '67A21699-DFE6-4CB6-96B6-E009FD389596')
                .Include(x => x.Student)
                .Include(x => x.Course);
return sc;
```

It gives me student details as null.

How do I get this sorted out?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the SQL column type of `course.Id`?

Comment: `sc` is an `IQueryable`. You need to call `.ToListAsync` to get the actual results.

Comment: @Dai -  course.Id is Guid

Comment: `x.CourseId == new Guid('67A21699-DFE6-4CB6-96B6-E009FD389596')`

Comment: @Charlieface - I did that, still the same result. I think it should be in the way I wrote the EF Query

Comment: @Dai - I did as you advised (sc is an IQueryable. You need to call .ToListAsync to get the actual results), but problem still not solved

Comment: Are entity relationships properly modelled in your EF context? Typically, for many-to-many relationship the auxiliary table maintaining that relationship would not be represented as an entity.

Comment: Can you post your class `StudentCourses`

Comment: @PeterSmith - I have added the StudentCourses class

Comment: Where are rhe relationships between `StudentCourses`, `Student`, and `Course` defined; the equivalent of the `joins` in the SQL.

Comment: Is your dbcontext have custom configuration like 'this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;' or '.AutoInclude(true)' on your 'modelBuilder'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to understand how to do that, you need to go back to basics

1. You need to study how to build a model in EF. There are many tutorials on the web; and SO discourages opinions; so I will just put a link to official [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) documentation. You will end up with something like this:

```
public class Student
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Note that there is no class `StudentCourses`!

2. You need to study the implementation of `many-to-many` relationship in Entity Framework 6. Again, you should start at official [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#other-relationship-patterns) documentation; but it is a complex topic - so you probably need to spend more time on some tutorials. In `DbContext` you will have something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Students>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Courses)
            .WithMany(p => p.Students)
```

Once you have basic understanding of that, writing a LINQ statement is quite straightforward. Remember, you are *NOT* converting SQL to LINQ!

```
var sc = _context.Courses
    .Where(x => x.CourseId == '67A21699-DFE6-4CB6-96B6-E009FD389596')
    .Select(c => new { 
        c.CourseId,
        c.Name,
        c.Students
    });
```

Also note - that whenever you use `Include()`, it's "code smell"; it means you need to review your design, and maybe study some more tutorials.

Comment: Why would the use of `Include()` be code smell?